# UIViewController changes orientation while told not to do so

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a `UIViewController` where I override those 2 methods:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

My device orientation is ticked for Portrait, Landscape Left & Right.

I cleaned the build folder.

My problem: when I go to landscape, the app changes the orientation.

Any idea what's wrong. I thought overriding those two methods should be enough but it seems not.

Comment: is this embeded in the UINavigationController?

Comment: Yes indeed. I actually added it very recently and I didn't think that it might be the cause.

Comment: Yes then since it is embeded in the UINavigationController , it is still rotated as the UINavigationControllers  shouldAutorotate() isnt overriden.

Comment: I'm suprised that it doesn't follow the rules of it's embedded view controller. How can I fix that?

Comment: create an extension for UINavigationController and override shouldAutorotate() and within it write return visibleViewController.shouldAutorotate() and override the shouldAutorotate() in your respective view controller

Comment: ill mention it as an answer as well

Comment: and this scenarois  also occurs when your view controller is embedded in a tab bar controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your view controller is embedded in a UINavigationController and overridding shouldAutorotate() in the respective view controller alone wont work since it checks the shouldAutoRotate() of the UINavigationController/UITabBarController and therefore you will have to create a extension of UINavigationController

```
extension UINavigationController {
    public override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return visibleViewController.shouldAutorotate()
    }
}
```

And within the respective view controller wherever you want to lock the orientation as per your requirement override shouldAutoRotate()

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I guess it goes the same for `supportedInterfaceOrientations`